MSSQL logs are not being rotated in AG setup
I have an MSSQL setup primary-secondary configured through availability group. I see the logs do not get rotated even after the full backup is executed daily and logs backup is taken after each hour on DELL Networker. Backup preference is set to "preferred secondary". There are 2 databases:
Now when I execute following command:
select name, log_reuse_wait_desc from sys.databases where name in ('jbpm','dawak');

On primary I get OLDEST_PAGE for one database and AVAILABILITY_REPLICA for another while on secondary I get OLDEST_PAGE for both Moreover the manual shrinking does no good either as it eats up even more space. So only option I am left with is to reconfigure the AG. One thing I have checked is backups are running fine. Anyone?

What Availability Type are you using, Synchronous or Asynchronous?

I am using synchronous commit

What do you mean by the logs don't get rotated? Are you saying they keep growing? What is the output of your log information from sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states? Does it show forward progress?

I checked in the table you mentioned, the last redone time is when I reconfigured AG while redo queue size is 10975139.

and yes, logs keep growing

can anyone guide as the issue persists
